# Norm of linear combination of vectors in the "same general direction"

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space (a Banach space if necessary) and $x, y \in X$ such that $||x|| \leq ||x + y||$ and $||y|| \leq ||x + y||$. (Intuitively, I take this to mean $x$ and $y$ are in the "same direction", since neither shortens the length of the other).

Here is what I want:

For $c > 0$, $||x|| \leq ||x + (1 + c)y||$ and $||(1 + c)y|| \leq ||x + (1 + c)y||$. That is, if two vectors are in the "same direction", then if you lengthen one of them the result is still in the "same direction". I am fairly confident this is true, though a counter-example would be as appreciated as a proof.

Here is what I have so far, (thanks to a professor):

Use Hahn-Banach to normalize the vector $x + y$ with $f \in X^*$ such that $f(\cdot) \leq ||\cdot||$ and $f(x + y) = ||x + y||$. Then note that $f(x) \leq ||x|| \leq ||x + y|| = f(x + y) \implies f(y) > 0$.

Now $||x|| \leq ||x + y|| = f(x + y) \leq f(x + y) + cf(y) = f(x + (1 + c)y) \leq ||x + (1 + c)y||$. This is the first desired inequality.

I can also get $||y|| + cf(y) \leq ||x + y|| + cf(y) = f(x + y) + cf(y) = f(x + (1 + c)y) \leq ||x + (1 + c)y||$

However, I am having trouble strengthening this to the desired second inequality. This isn't a problem I was assigned in class, just something I thought of on my own. Also not 100% sure it is true. Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Dunno how to help with the proof, but for what it's worth, the phrase 'same direction' in the title made me at least instead think (on an intuitive level) of $||x|| + ||y|| = ||x+y||$; I certainly was a bit surprised when I read the body.

Comment: Indeed I see how that could be confusing, I added the word "general" to the title to hopefully dissuade that interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not true in general. And I think looks true because your intuitive picture of $x$ and $y$ being in the "same direction" is not what the conditions $||x|| \leq ||x + y||$ and $||y|| \leq ||x + y||$ imply. I'll give a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself:

Take the vectors, in $(r,\theta)$ coordinates, to be $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (1, \frac{2\pi}{3})$. Then $x+y = (1, \frac{\pi}{3})$ satisfies the given conditions, even though $x$ and $y$ are not in the "same general direction". It is easy to show now that for *any* $c > 0$, we have $||(1 + c)y|| > ||x + (1 + c)y||$.